# concatenate a list of form fields and mixed text content inside another form field

Tags: javascript, dojo, concatenation

I am using the following web app, [ESRI GeoForm](https://github.com/Esri/geoform-template-js), and attempting to customize it for concatenation purposes. It is a private, internal to our organization only, form. So I can't share the form I am using other than through video or images.

[image: Form as it looks on our internal-only webserver]

So basically, when the users enter 'Address Number' and 'Address Prefix' and other pieces to the 'Address' I would like to concatenate those entries in the fields "Full Address" and "Full Name."

All of these fields are needed, but I would REALLY rather not require users to do a double input so many times. SO...

This is a Dojo app, built on ESRI's Javascript API. I am fairly comfortable with editing small Javascript scripts, and I've built fairly robust ones years ago, but I'm somewhat lost with such a complex and lengthy apps as this one. Luckily, I just had some developers in the GIT Hub group make a very similar change to add the ability to 'lock' form fields. I have been instructed that I could mimic their addition for the locked functionality for fields to add a concatenate functionality for the fields. So... onward I go.

My first step was to go to the JSON for the fields that are added. This JSON is in the [default.js](https://github.com/Esri/geoform-template-js/blob/master/config/defaults.js) file. I decided to utilize what I believe is an Array object as an attribute option. So, for example, when building the form in the JSON and selecting what fields are needed from the database and how to lay them out on the form you create these field attributes. To create a default value for one of these fields you would create an attribute like so:

...
"defaultValue" : "true"
...

What I've done for the concatenate option is to go with an entry like so:

...
"concantenated": [ "FIELD_ONE", "*space*", "FIELD_TWO", "*space*",... ],
...

My thoughts are that each HTML Form Field is identified with an ID that is equal to the actual field name. Like so...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-input-type="String" maxlength="20" id="ADDRNUM" placeholder="175" data-display-type="text">
```

That field populates the database field ADDRNUM and it uses that field name as the ID. So in my concatenator attribute when I feed a list of field names I can point to those HTML Form Fields via ID.

This way...  can be told to concatenate somehow, maybe like so?

('ADDRNUM').keyup(function () { ('FULLADDR').val(this.value); }

The problem I am having is I am not sure where, in the [main.js](https://github.com/Esri/geoform-template-js/blob/master/js/main.js) file I need to add the concatenation process/method/function?

If I follow the system used to [integrate a 'Locked' option that was just added a day ago](https://github.com/Esri/geoform-template-js/commit/b694c2d8198b61371c17a5ebaa1048491f68c233)... then I would need to duplicate the "**disabled: !!currentField.locked**" with something like **concantenated: !!currentField.concatenator** but I am lost as to where / how I integrate a concatenation method.

**UPDATE (10APR18):**
So I've begun adapting code under [[form folder]/js/main.js](https://github.com/Esri/geoform-template-js/blob/master/js/main.js) to test and work with this. I'm starting on line 772.

```
if (!!currentField.concantenated) {
domClass.add(formContent, "concantenated");
array.forEach(currentField.concantenated, function(entry, i){

    console.log(JSON.stringify(entry, null, 4));

    console.log( currentField );
    if(entry !== "_space_" || "_comma_")
    {
        console.log( "It is not _space_ nor _comma_ but rather " + entry );
        concatField = dom.byId(entry.stringify);
        console.log( concatField );

        testField = dom.byId('ADDRNUM');
        console.log( testField );

        test = on(concatField, 'click', 'foo');

        console.log( entry + " was just updated with foo");
    }

});
}
```

This is giving me some good feedback through the console.log and what I am finding out is that the fields I need to reference aren't created yet. Now I could just move the fields to the bottom of the JSON list in [[form folder]/config/default.js](https://github.com/Esri/geoform-template-js/blob/master/config/defaults.js)